# jsPDF Setup in Angular 4 failing on new jsPDF() Unexpected token <

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

jsPDF is failing trying to create a new jsPDF() with Unexpected token <, how can i get this to work?

I ran a npm install jspdf --save, then npm install @types/jspdf --save.
This enabled me to add the import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; in my component.

```
Component
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

public createPDF() {
    let doc = new jsPDF(); // this line fails with unexpected 
                              token <
}
```

FYI, If I comment out the let doc = new jsPDF the code compiles.
Not sure what is going on here any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Fyi, There are a lot of posts saying to add the script to the angular cli, but the project i'm using doesn't use the angular cli, so i can't import it there.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i figured it out, the issue was case and syntax.  The line that fixed it was:
'jspdf': 'npm:jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js', in the systemjs.config.js.  The reason it was failing for me was i had it as 'jsPDF': ... the capital PDF caused me a ton of headaches and thx to my co worker for the extra set of eyes.

Comment: Ok. thats why i asked. you imported it correctly. i thought you are using angular.json. Please remove down vote.

Comment: I didn't down vote it, plus I knew it wasn't imported correctly, and the question was how to import it correctly, not did u.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case I tried it with vanilla JS, I used min.js to import jsPDF. I had to use following code to get it working.

```
const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
```